# How to insert buttons in a specific column of a Javascript table?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Here is my table that contains data from my database:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    
     var $table = $('#table');
     $table.bootstrapTable({
          url: 'list-user.php',
          search: true,
          pagination: true,
          buttonsClass: 'primary',
          showFooter: true,
          minimumCountColumns: 2,
          columns: [{
              field: 'num',
              title: '#',
              sortable: true,
              },{
              field: 'username',
              title: 'Username',
              sortable: true,
              },{
              field: 'email',
              title: 'Email',
              sortable: true,
              },{
              field: 'country',
              title: 'Country',
              sortable: true,
              },{
              field: 'password',
              title: 'Password',
              sortable: true,
              },{
              field: 'level',
              title: 'Level',
              sortable: true,
              },{
              field: 'costumize',
              title: 'Costumize',
              sortable: false,
              }],
          });
</script>
```

And this is my php file:

```html
<?php 
 require 'conection.php';
   
   $sqltran = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM login ")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
  $arrVal = array();
   
  $i=1;
   while ($rowList = mysqli_fetch_array($sqltran)) {
          
      $name = array(
    'num' => $i,
       'username'=> $rowList['username'],
       'email'=> $rowList['email'],
       'country'=> $rowList['country'],
      'password'=> $rowList['password'],
      'level'=> $rowList['user_type']
    );  


   array_push($arrVal, $name); 
   $i++;   
   }
   echo  json_encode($arrVal);  
   mysqli_close($conn);  
?>
```

**update**

My html #table:

```html
<!-- show user list -->
<div class="container-full" style="margin: 0px;">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>
                USER LIST
            </h1>
        </div>


        <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading "> 
                <span class=""> User List of Bagus Gamestore             
              <br>
             </div>
                         
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <table  id="table"
                                data-show-columns="true"
                                data-height="460">
                        </table>
                 <!--Add record button-->
            <div class="pull-right"><button  type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" id="command-add" data-row-id="0">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> <a href="#popup" style="color: white;"> Record </button></div>  
              <!--end of add record button-->  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>              
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to add an edit/delete button for each row in the customize column, how can i do that ?

[Here is a picture of my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWuLV.png)

Any comment would be appreciated :) thank you

Comment: show your `#table` html

Comment: thank you for your response , i already update it